# what does dict() do compared to the dunder method __dict__?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am confused as to why when I do `dict(some_variable)` <--- and that some_variable is a class object it tells me that object is not iterable, but when i do `some_variable.__dict__` it provides me with the dictionary of the keys and values. Also where should I learn more about this... I am not an expert but trying to improve to begin my path into programming, sorry if this question may seem stupid.

Comment: Two very different things: `__dict__` holds an object's attributes, while `dict()` turns an iterable of pairs into a dictionary.

Comment: @schwobaseggl so if i understood correctly...correct me if im wrong:
dict([["hi", "thanks"], ["for", "helping"]]) will work because there are pairs inside of the iterable so it can pair them key : value . But then __dict__ will turn things like a class object attributes of self.name = name or self.height = height into a dictionary of the key being the "height"  (since the variable in  `__init__` is height) and the value of whatever self.height is? Where as a dict() can't do that, all it can do is turn an iterable that has other iterables inside of it into a dictionary?

Comment: The first part is correct. 
The second part is not. `__dict__` is not a dunder *method*, it is an attribute of an object (not all objects have it though) where the object stores its custom attributes. If you change a value in an object's `__dict__` the attribute will change.

Comment: @schwobaseggl  Part 1 = I think I get it. `__dict__` stores things like self.name = name and self.height = height , and when i do object.`__dict__` all those attributes that I had are stored into that dictionary where the key is the self.**name** (I mean only the bit after the dot) and the key is the value that was assigned to it.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Part 2 = Also where could I learn more about attributes similar to `__dict__` and dunder methods? I want to get to know all this kinda necessary stuff. Also if I were to def `__dict__` and then define what it should do then it breaks it for my object right, so if i then try to do `object.__dict__` it will do what my function told it to do? Thanks for reading

Comment: For dunder methods,  see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names